# Making filters based on checkboxes

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I do filters depending on checkboxes checked. Now I have only 2 checkbox and I need to cover all escenarios into `if` `else` conditionals like:

```
  if (!chkProjectTechs.Checked && !chkTeamLeader.Checked)
            {
                foreach (DataRowView list in lstTech.SelectedItems)
                {
                    var selectedEmpGuid = (Guid)list[0];
                    EmpGuid.Add(selectedEmpGuid);
                }
                parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
            }
            else if (!chkTeamLeader.Checked && chkProjectTechs.Checked)
            {
                foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
                {
                    EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
                }
                parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
            }
            else if (!chkProjectTechs.Checked && chkTeamLeader.Checked)
            {
                foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
                {
                    EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
                }
                parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
            }
            else if (chkProjectTechs.Checked && chkTeamLeader.Checked)
            {
                foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
                {
                    EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
                }
                parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);

                foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
                {
                    EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
                }
                parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
            }
```

But I need to add more checkboxes. For `foreach` checkbox I will add to my form  I need to add it to each conditional, and at the final of the day I will get very long code. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this code is working correctly?  It looks like parameters would be set to only team leaders in the fourth case, rather than to a combination of both.

Comment: Yes is working, when two boxes are checked it execute fourth case @Errorsatz

Comment: Also, what does lstTech.SelectedItems represent in the first case?

Comment: It's a list box, but I added validation to disable list box if any checkbox is selected  @Errorsatz

Comment: Please include the complete method. It would greatly help us to see the big-picture. If there still would be some undefined variables there, make sure to include their definitions too.

Comment: Also, please tag the appropriate technology (e.g. winforms,...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear from the code, but assuming your intent is to display the combination of all selected sets, or the result of a separate list box if no sets are selected, then you can do it with one check per set.

Assuming EmpGuid is a List or similar that starts out empty (if not, modify as appropriate), and using some Linq to clean it up:

```
if(chkProjectTechs.Checked)
{
    EmpGuid.AddRange(projectTechnicians.Select(x => x.EmpGuid));
}
if(chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    EmpGuid.AddRange(teamLeaders.Select(x => x.EmpGuid));
}
// Other cases here ...

if(!EmpGuid.Any())
{
    EmpGuid.AddRange(lstTech.SelectedItems.Select(row => (Guid)row[0]));
}
parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
```